# Creating a notification listener which runs permanently

Tags: java, android, service

I want to create an application which sends all my phone notifications to my computer.

Therefore I need to create a foreground NotificationListenerService which runs permanently. That means it needs to start at boot and continue running even if the app itself is not used by the user.

This is the code of my NotificationListenerService:

```
public class NotificationListener extends NotificationListenerService {

    @Override
    public void onNotificationPosted(StatusBarNotification sbn) {
        Bundle extras = sbn.getNotification().extras;

        Log.d("App", "Notification posted");
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Log.d("App", "Service started");

        startForeground(1, new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, NotificationChannel.DEFAULT_CHANNEL_ID)
                .setContentTitle(getText(R.string.notification_title))
                .setContentText(getText(R.string.notification_body))
                .setContentIntent(PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, new Intent(this, MainActivity.class), 0))
                .build());

        return START_STICKY;
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, the debug messages are never printed which probably means my service is not registered properly although I cannot find anything I did wrong in my AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<service
    android:name=".NotificationListener"
    android:permission="android.permission.BIND_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SERVICE">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.service.notification.NotificationListenerService" />
    </intent-filter>
</service>
```

I did not implement anything yet to start my service at boot. I first want the service itself get working.

What am I doing wrong? What do I miss? And even if it would work, would that be enough to keep the service running (after it is started automatically at boot)?

Comment: Did you enable your app to have "Notification access" (or however it's phrased) in the device Settings? It's not done automatically. The user has to manually allow your app access to their notifications.

Comment: What exactly do you mean? I looked through the settings and it is allowed to send notifications. Though I wasn't able to give a specific permission to the app in the settings. But I see some apps asking for the permissions they need. Could I do the same with my app?

Comment: Notification access should be a Security setting, so wherever that might be on your particular device. It's not the regular "Allow these apps to show notifications at all" settings. It should say something specifically about access to, or maybe listening for, etc., notifications from other apps. There is an `Intent` action that you could use to direct the user to the specific page, if it's available: [`Settings.ACTION_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SETTINGS`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.html#ACTION_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SETTINGS).

Comment: I gave my app now the permissions but unfortunately, I still cannot find the debug message of the service starting.

Comment: Remove your `onStartCommand()` override. It's not necessary, and might be causing issues. Apart from that, I just threw the rest of it into a fresh project, and it works as expected for me.

Comment: Are you sure I should remove it? To make my service be running permanently, it must be a foreground service. And therefore I need to run the startForeground method which is normally done in the onStartCommand method. If you leave the onStartCommand method in your project, is a notification shown?

Comment: You're not handling the running of that `Service`. The system is. Once it's enabled to have access to notifications, it will run as needed. You don't need to worry about starting it, or about its foreground status.

Comment: It seems to be working now, thanks. But won't that service shut up after some time? And do I still need to launch it manually after boot?

Comment: No, once its access is enabled, the system takes over handling your `Service`. It won't be running all of the time, but it doesn't need to, 'cause you're not getting notifications every second of every day. If it needs to be started to handle one, the system will do so. I would advise to pay close attention to your logs, however, while you design and test this, as it's quite easy for something to error out in the background without any other indication, and it might seem like your `Service` just stopped working for no reason.

Comment: @MikeM., Did you mean remove annotation "@Override" or remove supper method "super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId)".

Comment: @CauCuKien I meant, remove it altogether. The only method they need in the example given is `onNotificationPosted()`.

Comment: @MikeM. I got it. Thanks. Does startForeground() is usefull for NotificationListernService to keep it not disconnected? Because I read somewhere that call startForeground() will keep the service work without disconnecting.

Comment: No. That's what I explain in my last two comments to coolguy2000. The system handles starting the `Service`, not you.